# How Chain Map or Chain Filter inside of Angular Http request that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, json, angular, lodash

I have some data that I am rejecting from a json array with lodash. I need to reject multiple key values that aren't desired.

I am thinking I can either chain map and use the reject function again or possibly write a predicate function for the reject method to use.

I think I may be overthinking the issue here, can someone help me wrap my head around this? Do I need to switch over to an observable for this to work?

I want to be able to reject BEER, LIQUOR, WINE, ETC. The data is nested as well.

Here is an example JSON object
[image]

Here is my service.

```
getMenuByLocationID(locationID) {
return this._http.get('/api/locations/menu', {params: {locationID: locationID}})
.map((response: Response) =>
_.reject(response.json(), {
  _embedded: { 
    menu_categories: [ { 
      name: 'BEER'
    } ]
  }
}))
.toPromise()
.catch(this.handleError);
```

}

Comment: Do you use the `Http` service or the new `HttpClient` service ?

Comment: Import {http} from @angular/http

Comment: What is the expected result ? If you call `getMenuByLocationID(someId).then((expectedData) => ...)`, what is the expected value for `expectedData` ?

Comment: The expected result would be all items that aren't BEER, WINE, LIQUOR. Currently I just get everything that isn't BEER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `_.reject` can handle multiple values in its matching criteria. So, you can use `_.reject` multiple time with each of your rejected values (BEER, WINE, ...) but it might not be the best solution.

Instead, you can use `_.reject` with a custom predicate function that test all your values at once. But you have to write this test, I don't think lodash offer a built in solution. But I can be wrong...

Something like that

```
gettMenuByLocationID (locationID) {
  return this._http.get('/api/locations/menu', {params: {locationID: locationID}})
             .map((response: Response) => {
               let data = _.reject(response.json(), {_embedded: {menu_categories: [{name: 'BEER'}]}})
               data     = _.reject(data, {_embedded: {menu_categories: [{name: 'WINE'}]}})
               return _.reject(data, {_embedded: {menu_categories: [{name: 'WHATEVER'}]}})
             })
             .toPromise()
             .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

Comment: That's what I asking. How do I use it multiple times in a returned promise as shown above.

Comment: @GarrettSanderson I added some code. That way, you filter more and more your response depending on its categories.